Can't get message passing working when calling a class method from main(). The class method contains the call to the mesage passing function
I am attempting to send a message from an OOT module to a gr-display module. This task is part of a large project with a complicated flowgraph. Therefore I am going to provide only the pertinent part of the code. I hope this is sufficient to understand my problem with some explanation.
The ft8_rxtx OOT module is connected to the gr-display module in the flowgraph.
The code is as follows:
from gnuradio import gr
import pmt

class ft8_rxtx(gr.basic_block):
    """
    docstring for block ft8_rxtx
    """
    def __init__(self, ptt_button, band_selector):
        gr.basic_block.__init__(self,
            name="ft8_rxtx",
            in_sig=[],
            out_sig=[])
        self.ptt_button = ptt_button
        self.band_selector = band_selector
        self.portName = "text_out"
        self.message_port_register_out(pmt.intern(self.portName))
 
    def set_FT8(self, FT8_button):
        if FT8_button == 1:
            self.send_msg("Help")
        PMT_msg = pmt.to_pmt("Help")
        self.message_port_pub(pmt.intern(self.portName), PMT_msg)
            main()
        else:
            quit()

    def send_msg(self, msg):
        PMT_msg = pmt.to_pmt(msg)
        self.message_port_pub(pmt.intern(self.portName), PMT_msg)


def main():

    gen_msg = ft8_rxtx(0,1)
    gen_msg.send_msg("MAIN")
 
In main() I am calling send_msg as evidenced by the use of a print statement in the method which correctly displays MAIN. However, the message_port_pub() does not send the message to the gr-display.
 

If set_FT8 is called, the self.send_msg(“Help”) executes properly and the self.message_port_pub() executes properly. Both send the message “Help” to the gr-display.
Thus, the message passing works when calling send_msg from a class method but does not work when called from main(). Why not? What am I leaving out?

It looks like your functions set_FT8 and send_msg are intended to be methods of the ft8_rxtx class. They are not

This isn't valid Python; you need to make send_msg a method of your class, not a free-standing function.

set_FT8 and send_msg are class methods in the actual code. For some reason the indents did not show in the code in the question. I cannot see how to properly edit the question to change the indents.

the code as pasted does not have the two functions indented, I checked before answering :) Anyways, assuming it really is in your code: what does the "Message Debug" block say about the messages output by your block?

I added a Message Debug block and connected the output of the ft8_rxtx block to the print input of the Message Block. I tested it by observing that the Message Block print is "Help" as it should be. There is no print for the call from main().

but main is only called from within the block itself, right?

main() is called only from set_FT8() which is a method of the class.

Am I to assume there is no solution here? Is this a bug? Or am I trying to do something that is not allowed?

@Jim I sadly can't tell you, I have not had a great idea of how to investigate. My suspicion is that you're trying to pass a message at a point in time where the flow graph isn't running already, and thus it can't pass messages, but I'm not sure.

@ Marcus Muller Perhaps you are correct about the flowgraph. I am actually making the call in main() as a test in order to solve an issue which is part of MUCH more complicated code. I am not able to send a message from a part of the code which is not a class method but is in the block. The flowgraph is already running at that point. However, there may be a separate issue causing this problem. You might be wondering why I just haven't made this a class method - that's a long story. It's a situation where the code as it evolved works - "if it ain't broke don't fix it". I will re-investigate.
